# Fixed Point for Newton's Method

Tags: newton-raphson

If a polynomial function has at least one real root, will Newton's Method **always** converge to one of those real roots? (no attracting fixed point). Is there a counterexample where the guess does NOT start with a horizontal tangent line (i.e when the slope of the tangent line is 0)?

Comment: No.  Consider $x^3-1$ where you start at $0$.

Comment: It will surely converge, if you can wisely choose the first point, from where the iteration starts.

Comment: Post edit:  still no.  Try $x^3-2x+2$ and guess $0$.

Comment: These sort of failures are well documented...I suggest an online search.

Comment: @lulu Question for you: what do you know about the case when the polynomial has only real roots?

Comment: @cnikbesku  I don't think that matters...the oscillation problem is just a coincidence  between the slopes of tangents.  I'll see if I can design an example.

Comment: @lulu Ok, thank you, I see. I think I constructed an example myself.

Comment: Just adapting my first one, $f(x)=x^3-2x-1$, guess $.429926366\cdots$. So, not a pretty example but I think it proves the point.

Comment: @lulu I also found an example: $f(x)=x^4-3x^2+1$ and guess a real root of $7x^4-9x^2-1$.

Comment: My safest bet is that it converges for almost all initial values, so that if you add a random value to the root after each iteration you should come about that close to a root.

Comment: I cannot say specifically about polynomials, but it is easy to define smooth functions where one has to get very lucky in your initial position for Newton's method to converge. A safer bet is to identify two starting values where the function has different signs, then if Newton's method ever tells you to leave the interval, ignore it to toss in a bisection step instead. Either way, shrink the interval based on the value of the function at the next estimate. This guarantees convergence, while allowing for Newton's method to give fast convergence when it is actually working.